# Error with trying to install packages via cmd line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting the following error with Python when I try to install packages via the cmd line. It's been running smoothly for a few months now and this is the first headache that it's given me,

Has anyone bumped into this before?

```
C:\>python -m pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS, expanduser
  File "C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\compat.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.util import IS_PYOPENSSL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of virtual environment or similar solution? (Conda, virtualenv, pipenv, etc.)

Comment: @Grygger Can you upvote the solution? Also, I think you have accidentally created a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution from github:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6261#issuecomment-465067873

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
python3.7 -m ensurepip
pip install --upgrade pip
```

In your case delete

```
C:\Users\agryga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip
```

then run

```
python3.7 -m ensurepip
pip install --upgrade pip
```